# GGally: How can I remove the density plots in ggpairs/ggscatmat, and add a heat aesthetic to the correlation section?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm starting to get to grips with the `GGally` package and I'm a bit overwhelmed with the options. What I'd like is to sort of combine `ggpairs()` together with the heat aesthetic you get from `ggcorr()`, and to replace the density plots with the relevant variable names.

```
library(tidyverse); library(GGally)

ggpairs(mpg[,c("displ","year","cyl","cty","hwy")])
```

[image]

with

```
ggcorr(mpg[,c("displ","year","cyl","cty","hwy")], label = TRUE)
```

[image]

To get something like this (obviously with the correlation figures rotated correctly):

[image]